# Run a Python GUI Application on Startup with Sudo Rights

Tags: sudo, startup, startup-applications

I have an Python Executable which has to be launched with sudo Rights on Start up.
Things i Tried:

1. a.Added the Sudo rights in /etc/sudoers 
   [sudoer file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qc17K.png)

   b.Added the Path in the Startup Application [GUI Startup Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqK4e.png) 
   on reboot Application is Launched but without Sudo Rights
2. created a Launch script to launch the application and added the Script in /etc/rc.local [rc.local file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dm1h.png) [Launch script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSktV.png)

After Reboot nothing happens. When i run the Launch script individually it runs.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you on?  17.10 uses Wayland by default, which *does not permit `sudo`/`root` GUI applications from running* in the user's session.

Comment: currently am using Ubuntu 14.04...